# Django: how to add a field to an existing model without much rewrite of the code

Tags: django, django-models

our website lists local city events. It's Django-based so there's a lot of code related to 'event' model. Until now, we work only in one city and so all the events mean to be local.

Now we need to extend the website to another city. This means 'event' model gets a new attribute 'city', and our middleware will set a global value CurrentCity based on geoip.

We need to extend 'event' model so it would filter only records where 'city' attribute equals to CurrentCity value. There is too much code in different views and models working with the 'event' so we can't update each module.

Is there any single place to patch that would make our 'event' model aware of the CurrentCity value?

Answer (score 0):

Depending a lot in your structure and Django version I think you have 2 options.

## South

The best one is to install the application "South". I don't know if you already know it or you're using it but I think it should be your first option.

In case you're not using it, you should do this steps:

1. Install with `pip install South`
2. Create your first migration with:

   - `python manage.py schemamigration YOURAPPNAME --initial`
3. You need to fake this migration, because you have already the fullfilled database so you need to do:

   - `python manage.py migrate YOURAPPNAME --fake`
4. Add the *new* field to the model Event in the file models.py
5. Generate the new migration to make South create the new field in your database with:

   - `python manage.py schemamigration YOURAPPNAME --auto`
6. Final step, execute the migration created with:

   - `python manage.py migrate YOURAPPNAME`

*Tips*

- `--initial` for the first migration `--auto` for the rest
- The initial migration is faked because you already have tables in your database, if you try to migrate without the fake it will return error "Table already exists"

## New Model City

Another option, in case you can't modify your actual Model, or maybe if it's too messy, another option is to generate an externa Model City like this:

```
class City(models.Model):
    event_foreign = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    event_many = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField....
    postal_code = models.CharField....
    # etc...
```

I don't know wich is optimal for you, a Foreign Key or a ManyToMany, depends if a City can have more than 1 Event or no, it's your choice.

When you have a model like this you can access from this City model to the Event (because of the ForeignKEy or ManyToMany) but this relation goes also in the other direction, if you have an Event you can get the City/cities related to it I'm gonna show two examples:

**Example 1 using Foreign Key**

```
city = City.objects.get(id=1)
city.event  # Returns event

event = Event.objects.get(id=1)
event.city  # Returns city
```

**Example 2 using Many to Many**

```
city = City.objects.get(id=1)
city.event.all()  # Returns a list of events

event = Event.objects.get(id=1)
event.city_set.all()  # Returns a list of cities
```